# Duplicate the CURRENT STATE of a tab in Firefox or Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, tabs

In both Firefox and Chrome, you can duplicate tabs by right-clicking the tab and choosing "Duplicate Tab". (In Firefox, you can also Ctrl+drag the tab.)

However, when a tab is duplicated in this way, it seems that what the browser does is simply open a new tab with the same URL and then **reload** the website. What I want to do instead is duplicate the tab's **current state**.

For example, if the website is lazy-loaded (loads more content when you scroll down), I want to duplicate the tab with the additional content already loaded, instead of having to scroll again to load it, which is what actually happens when I duplicate a tab in these two browsers.

Is there some kind of hidden browser feature or extension that can do that?

Comment: This also annoying if you've edited a bunch of dynamic form elements on the page, and then decide you want to duplicate the tab while preserving the form state.

Answer (score -1):

The Duplicate Tab Shortcut extension for Chrome will allow you to create a keybinding to duplicate a tab. The extension can be installed [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/duplicate-tab-shortcut/klehggjefofgiajjfpoebdidnpjmljhb).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1130088)

Comment: Thanks! But this does not answer my question. As I said, I know there is a "Duplicate Tab" option, but it doesn't duplicate the **current state** of the tab, it just opens a new tab and reloads the current website in the new tab, in its default state. This extension simply creates a keyboard shortcut that does the thing I said I **don't** want to do. What I want is that, for example, if I entered something into a form, then the duplicate tab will retain the form input.